# INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I'm having trouble optimising a simple SQL query but having serious issue with timing. I've written it three times and none of them work. Here is the original one I was hoping to work:

```
SELECT RSKADDR.*
FROM EDW_BASE.RCI_RISK_ADDRESS RSKADDR
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT COVER_RISK_ID
  FROM  EDW_BASE.RCI_COVER_RISK_MASTER RSKMASTER
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT CONTACT_ID, FOLLOW_UP_DATE 
  FROM EDW_STG.STG_CIM_SVOM03
  WHERE OUTSTANDING = 1 AND QUEUE = 'CIM Update for Contact Address') ADDR_WF
  ON RSKMASTER.CONTACT_CODE = ADDR_WF.CONTACT_ID
  WHERE RSKMASTER.IS_STORNO != 1 
        AND RSKMASTER.PRODUCT_CODE = 'HOME' 
        AND  ADDR_WF.FOLLOW_UP_DATE >= RSKMASTER.COVER_EFF_START_DATE 
        AND RSKMASTER.POLICY_STATUS_CODE = 'POLICY'
        AND ADDR_WF.FOLLOW_UP_DATE <= RSKMASTER.COVER_EFF_END_DATE 
  ) ACTVRSK
ON ACTVRSK.COVER_RISK_ID = RSKADDR.RISK_ID
```

The code in the first inner join works fast all the way to the end. That is, the second SELECT query (within the INNER JOIN query of the first and main SELECT query) works fast without a problem. The problem arises when I integrate the second SELECT query inside the INNER JOIN of the main SELECT query (select RSKADDR.*).

Then it seems the execution is never ending!

I tried other ways and same result:

```
SELECT RSKADDR.*
FROM EDW_BASE.RCI_RISK_ADDRESS RSKADDR

INNER JOIN EDW_BASE.RCI_COVER_RISK_MASTER RSKMASTER
ON RSKMASTER.COVER_RISK_ID = RSKADDR.RISK_ID
   AND RSKMASTER.IS_STORNO != 1 
   AND RSKMASTER.PRODUCT_CODE = 'HOME' 
   AND RSKMASTER.POLICY_STATUS_CODE = 'POLICY'

INNER JOIN EDW_STG.STG_CIM_SVOM03 ADDR_WF
ON OUTSTANDING = 1 AND QUEUE = 'CIM Update for Contact Address'
   AND RSKMASTER.CONTACT_CODE = ADDR_WF.CONTACT_ID
   AND ADDR_WF.FOLLOW_UP_DATE >= RSKMASTER.COVER_EFF_START_DATE
   AND ADDR_WF.FOLLOW_UP_DATE <= RSKMASTER.COVER_EFF_END_DATE
```

It's such an easy query and can't get it to work. How can I do this?

Comment: can you share your schema and data

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately can't share data as it involves private information. what would you like to know about the scheme? could i help explaining, without sharing the whole schema?

Comment: just can you share sample data and schema not exact

Comment: What is more important is what columns uniquely identify a record in RCI_COVER_RISK_MASTER and STG_CIM_SVOM03.

Comment: Press caps lock

Comment: RSKMASTER table: COVER_RISK_ID is unique identifer   and for RSKADDR table: RSKADDR.RISK_ID is unique identifer. for ADDR_WF, CONTACT_ID is identifier

Comment: So `rci_risk_address` and `rci_cover_risk_master` have the same key (the risk ID)? Why is this two separate tables then instead of only one?

Comment: "Doesn't work"?  But what it is supposed to do?  Are you asking about syntax?  Performance?  Wrong results?  What?

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` is a costly operation and seldom needed. It often indicates a bad database design or a poorly written query. In your query you are even doing this repeatedly; that doesn't look good.

The second query looks much better. As you say you get the same result, `DISTINCT` in the first query *was* superfluous obviously.

I see you doing joins, but all you select is data from one table. So why join then? Select from the table you want data from and put your criteria in `WHERE` where it belongs.

The following query may be faster, because it plainly shows that we are simply checking whether we find matches in the other tables or not. But then, MySQL was known for not performing too well with `IN` clauses, so that may depend on the Version you are using.

```
select *
from edw_base.rci_risk_address
where risk_id in
(
  select rm.cover_risk_id
  from edw_base.rci_cover_risk_master rm
  where rm.is_storno <> 1 
    and rm.product_code = 'HOME' 
    and rm.policy_status_code = 'POLICY'
    and exists
    (
      select * 
      from edw_stg.stg_cim_svom03 adr 
      where adr.contact_id      = rm.contact_code
        and adr.follow_up_date >= rm.cover_eff_start_date
        and adr.follow_up_date <= rm.cover_eff_end_date 
        and adr.outstanding = 1
        and adr.queue = 'CIM Update for Contact Address'
    )
);
```

Anyway, with your second query or with mine, I suppose the following indexes would help:

```
create index idx1 on rci_cover_risk_master
(
   product_code, 
   policy_status_code, 
   is_storno, 
   contact_code, 
   cover_eff_start_date, 
   cover_eff_end_date, 
   cover_risk_id
);

create index idx2 on stg_cim_svom03
(
  contact_id, 
  follow_up_date, 
  outstanding, 
  queue
);

create index idx3 on rci_risk_address(risk_id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. your code makes much more sense and it's so much cleaner. It's still taking too long for the query to get executed but I think this is due to badly designed schema. I wonder if I should use temporary table and do the select on that?

Comment: The indexes don't help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :(

Comment: I don't have any idea where the DBMS is messing up then. Looks so simple: find risk masters for the given criteria whose address matches further criteria. Then get the rci_risk_address by primary key. Looking at the explain plan might help, but I am no MySQL guy, so someone else may have to step in here.

Comment: This is Oracle database. as you mentioned this query is super simple. It shouldn't be messy and taking too long to execute. I'll wait to see if anything else comes along. Thanks again.

Comment: Oracle? You have tagged it MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

From the query, you only need `RSKADDR` data, so no need for an INNER JOIN. You can do the same with `EXISTS` keyword. Try the below query

```
SELECT RSKADDR.*
FROM EDW_BASE.RCI_RISK_ADDRESS RSKADDR
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM  EDW_BASE.RCI_COVER_RISK_MASTER RSKMASTER
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 
  FROM EDW_STG.STG_CIM_SVOM03
  WHERE OUTSTANDING = 1 AND QUEUE = 'CIM Update for Contact Address') ADDR_WF
  AND RSKMASTER.CONTACT_CODE = ADDR_WF.CONTACT_ID
  AND RSKMASTER.IS_STORNO != 1 
        AND RSKMASTER.PRODUCT_CODE = 'HOME' 
        AND  ADDR_WF.FOLLOW_UP_DATE >= RSKMASTER.COVER_EFF_START_DATE 
        AND RSKMASTER.POLICY_STATUS_CODE = 'POLICY'
        AND ADDR_WF.FOLLOW_UP_DATE <= RSKMASTER.COVER_EFF_END_DATE 
  ) 
AND RSKMASTER.COVER_RISK_ID = RSKADDR.RISK_ID
)
```

Note : I have not tested query as no schema available.

Comment: Syntactical mistakes require no schema